# Facebook - sendRequestToManyRecipients() back url should not be to https but http

Tags: facebook

I have a problem.
I'm developing with PHP an app for facebook in IFrame and I use the function sendRequestToManyRecipients() so:

```
    FB.init({
        appId  : '<?=APP_ID?>',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        oauth: true
      });
    function sendRequestToManyRecipients() {
      FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'xxxxxxxx'
      });
```

The Problem is when the user invited click on request, the url is https://apps.facebook.com/myapp. 
My App doesn't work, because the right url is http://... and I have a blank page. The request doesn't get the index.php so I can't to do a redirect.

I tried FB._https = false but that doesn't help.

Can I change that url?
My app needs http and not https.

Comment: i put in my code FB._https = false but it's the same. The request is always in htpps don't get my index.php

Answer (score 0):

whether the url is https or http depends on the user facebook settings. Only users with http will be able to view the index. Buy a certificate to solve your problem.